# OpenMP reduction clause does not work for a big long int for loop count

Tags: c++, openmp, atomic

There is a following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <omp.h>

const long int N=1000000000L;

class Counter {
public:
  Counter():n(0),N(0){}
  void operator()()
  {
    if(n==INT_MAX)
    {
  #pragma omp atomic update
      ++N;
  #pragma omp atomic write
      n=1;
    }
    else
    {    
  #pragma omp atomic update
      ++n;
    }
  }
  long int GetTotalCount()
  {
    return (static_cast<long int>(n)+static_cast<long int>(N)*static_cast<long int>(INT_MAX));
  }
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, Counter & counter)
  {
    o<<counter.GetTotalCount()<<" ("<<counter.N<<","<<counter.n<<") = "
     <<static_cast<long int>(counter.N)*static_cast<long int>(counter.INT_MAX)+static_cast<long int> 
       (counter.n)
 <<std::endl;
return o;
  }
private:
  const int INT_MAX=std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
  int n;
  int N;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  Counter counter;
#pragma omp parallel for simd
  for(long int i=0; i<N; ++i)
  {
    if(i%2==0) counter();
  }
  const auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  std::cout<<"N="<<N<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Total count="<<counter;
  auto time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-begin).count();
  std::cout<<"t="<<time<<" ms"<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It works properly with all N <=1000000000 and gives the following output:

> N=1000000000
>
> Total count=500000000 (0,500000000) = 500000000
>
> t=11297 ms

But if to make N 10 times bigger, the output is incorrect (2nd line):

> N=10000000000
>
> Total count=705032704 (0,705032704) = 705032704
>
> t=112660 ms

The second line here must be

> Total count=500000000 (2,500000000) = 705032706

I can't understand why the program works incorrectly at N=1e10, although N is *long int*.

Comment: Your question title mentions "OpenMP reduction clause". Yet, there aren't any in the code shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race condition in the check:

```
if(n==INT_MAX)
{
    // Nothing prevents another thread to read n here and enter the same branch
    #pragma omp atomic update
    ++N;
    #pragma omp atomic write
    n=1;
}
```

Hence, two threads may both decide to reset `n` and increment `N` concurrently.

Besides that, you would also have to read `n` atomically for the if check itself, though that is not sufficient alone.

Overall, you are better off using an actual OpenMP reduction or a custom built reduction and also sufficiently large datatypes that support actual atomic operations.

Comment: If to add int n; #pragma omp atomic read x=n; if(n==INT_MAX){...}, it does not help. If there is a race condition, why the code works properly for N=10^9 ans smaller?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the answer, just reading `n` atomically for the check is not sufficient.

Comment: A race condition is *never required* to actually cause a detectable problem. It is common for a race condition to manifest as a problem under random or totally obscure conditions.  In you case, however, it is trivial: As long as `n < INT_MAX` *no* thread will enter the problematic first if branch.

Comment: Oh, of course. But what should I do to get the code to work? You wrote that I may use actual OpenMP reduction. Did You mean to get rid of #pragma omp atomic update and #pragma omp atomic write and use reduction(+:N,n) clause in #pragma omp parallel for simd line?

Comment: Yes, you either use `reduction(+ : n)` with a sufficiently large type of `n`, or declare a custom reduction. For the latter, I think you can just use `+` by implementing a compatible "big number" class that supports initialization from int and `operator+` on itself. If that doesn't work, use `declare reduction`.

Comment: Excuse me, don't understand how I can use reduction(+:n) inside the class Counter. As far as I understand, I can only use reduction in #pragma omp parallel for clause before the for loop and can't use it inside the class.